# JavaScript - Drawing a Circle

Tags: javascript, rendering

I know there are already libraries for drawing a circle in JavaScript but I wanted to know how the actual maths of it works. Unfortunately there is no MathOverflow and I would of thought that with the number of programmers that are active here, someone will know what formula or concepts I need to use.

Comment: for those curious, there is a mathoverflow.net, but it allows only graduate level mathematics questions and wasn't made by the SO creators, so its a little different from our other sites. Fortunately there is a stackexchange 2.0 site for this, so if you don't get a good answer here, then that'd be the next place to look. http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ORLY? http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: if you post some libraries and their specific functions we might be able to help more. Take a look at their documentation as well.

Comment: http://codepen.io/dcdev/pen/upjDy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, there is a 'math overflow': https://math.stackexchange.com/

However, the formula you need to use is along these lines.

```
x = radius*Math.cos(angle) + centerX;
y = radius*Math.sin(angle) + centerY;
```

Comment: Comments posted by answers can be down-vote magnets sometimes.